# What is the shorter way of saying - "I am sharing my understanding, in a hope to get corrected"?

Tags: idioms, terminology, idiom-requests, internet, initialisms

I am looking for a concise way of saying or writing, "I am sharing my understanding about blah, in a hope to get corrected". The phrase "IMHO" expresses part of the idea, but does not necessarily imply that the speaker is seeking correction.

Comment: It does, on the surface,  imply that the speaker wants to be corrected. Speakers can say a lot about of things without really meaning them. Speakers can also make indirect requests. *I hope you correct me* is an indirect request. It can be said ingeniously by someone who  really doesn't want correcting, but then so can a lot of things. One can also say the imperative *Correct me if I'm wrong,  but...* with zero interest in people actually correcting them.

Comment: What's more important than actual wording is perceived speaker intention. If you think a  person is sincerely inviting correction, then by all means do so, gently if necessary.

Comment: If I'm not sure I'm correct I add the question "What do you think?" after my statement.

Comment: What @AlMaki said.  “Here’s my take.  What do you think?”

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to open with "Is this right?" and/or to close with "Is that right?"

Answer (score 0):

You could say "... and I'm speaking under correction." To indicate that you may be wrong when you state something, another approach could be to say x,y, and z but to add "but don't quote me on this" at the end.

Comment: What is the opposite of preface?, I could not think of the word when you add something to the end of a sentence.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't seem idiomatic to me. Is it? Maybe if you included supporting evidence or a reference, if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: @NeilMeyer I've seen the term "postface" used but only a few times.